# Why isn't UIButton's exclusiveTouch property set to YES by default?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I'm sure there are a lot of reasons why someone would like to have more than one button accept touches at the same time. However, most of us only need one button to be pressed at one time (for navigation, for something to be presented modally, to present a popover, a view, etc.).

So, why would Apple set the `exclusiveTouch` property of `UIButton` to NO by default?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very old question, but deserves clarification IMO.

**Despite the very misleading method documentation from Apple** a view "A" with exclusiveTouch set will prevent other views from receiving events **so long as A is processing some event itself**  (e.g. set a button with exclusiveTouch and put a finger on it, this will prevent other views in the window from being interacted with, but interaction with them will follow the usual pattern once the finger from the exlusiveTouch-item is removed).

Another effect is preventing view A from receiving events as long as some other view is interacted with (keep a button without exclusiveTouch set pressed, and the ones with exclusiveTouch will not be able to receive events as well).

You can still set a button in your view to exclusiveTouch and interact with the others, just not at the same time, as this simple test UIViewController will prove (once the correct bindings in the IB are set for both Outlets and Actions):

```
#import "FTSViewController.h"

@interface FTSViewController ()
- (IBAction)button1up:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button2up:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button1down:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)button2down:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button1, *button2;
@end

@implementation FTSViewController

- (IBAction)button1up:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button1 up");
}

- (IBAction)button2up:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button2 up");
}

- (IBAction)button1down:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button1 down");
}

- (IBAction)button2down:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button2 down");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Guarantees that button 1 will not receive events *unless* it's the only receiver, as well as
    // preventing other views in the hierarchy from receiving touches *as long as button1 is receiving events*
    // IT DOESN'T PREVENT button2 from being pressed as long as no event is being intercepted by button1!!!
    self.button1.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    // This is the default. Set for clarity only
    self.button2.exclusiveTouch = NO;
}
@end
```

In light of this, the only good reason IMHO for Apple not to set exclusiveTouch to YES for every UIView subclass is that it would have made the implementation of complex gestures a real PITA, including probably some of the gestures we are already accustomed to in composite UIView subclasses (like UIWebView), as setting selected views to exclusiveTouch=NO (like button) is faster than doing a recursive exclusiveTouch=YES on pretty much everything just to enable multitouch.

The drawback of this is that in many cases the counter intuitive behaviour of UIButtons and UITableViewCells (among others...) might introduce weird bugs and make testing more tricky (as it happened to me like... 10 minutes ago? :( ).

Hope it helps

Comment: I just made a UIView category that makes exclusiveTouch YES for all UIView and haven't had any issues

Comment: @jjxtra How to do that, which method to override?

Comment: I believe he created a subclass of UIView and set exclusiveTouch to Yes in init method. Doesn't really work for me cuz I am looking for easy way to make touches exclusive for all views in my project without copy pasting same thing in many places (i am lazy :p)

Answer (score -1):

the `UIView` property `exclusiveTouch` means the view (button) is the ONLY thing in that window that can be interacted with if it is set to `YES`. As stated in the docs: Setting this property to YES causes the receiver to block the delivery of touch events to other views in the same window. The default value of this property is NO.

Therefore, it is the common behavior that you might have multiple buttons or interaction controls/views in a window and want `exclusiveTouch` set to `NO`.

If you set this property to `YES` for any UIView subclass in a window, you can not interact with anything else in the window for as long as that property is set to `YES`. That means if you initialize a button with `exclusiveTouch = YES`, but also have a table view or another button or a scroll view or any other view that is based on interaction, it will not respond to any touches.

Comment: Suppose I have 2 buttons as subviews of the same view. If I don't set `exclusiveTouch` to NO on both buttons and then later if the user presses them both at the same time, both will call their action methods. And if their action methods conflict for some reason (say both of them push a different view controller to the navigation stack), the application crashes, hence my question.

Comment: Jesse: your explanation is in line with the documentation, so it's not your fault, but since the original documentation is misleading IMO, you are still giving false information: exlusiveTouch *doens't prevent* touch events to other buttons in the view (as both your explanation and the docs seem to imply), it just prevent other view from receiving events *while the one with exclusiveTouch is handling some* (as well as preventing the exlusiveTouch view from receiving events if other views are processing some as well...)

Comment: Also incorrect - The documentation is misleading. Corrected: "causes the receiver to block the delivery of touch events *if it's currently receiving touch events itself*". To do a test run and prove that this answer is wrong, set up a xib with two buttons, two IBActions that log two different messages, setExclusiveTouch:YES on both in viewDidLoad. Use the "alt + click" to do multitouch on the simulator and tap both buttons (use the shift key to recenter the multi-touch control). You can interact individually on each button but not with multitouch (but you can if you'd setExclusiveTouch:NO)

Answer (score -1):

exclusiveTouch simply means that any view underneath your UIButton will not receive the touch events.

It's set to no by default because you typically want the view underneath to receive these events.  For example, if you have a UIButton on top of a scroll view and the user wants to scroll.  You want the scrollView to scroll even if they begin with their finger on the UIButton.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate, @Jesse got it right. Setting this property to YES causes the receiver to block the delivery of touch events to other views in the same window.

Comment: it doesn't work that way (although the documentation says so): the flag only effect is to guarantee that other views will not receive  touch event *at the same time* with the owner of the flag (more or less). I did actually test that: see my answer for details.

Comment: Simply reflecting the comments above me - that's not how this property affects the view. It'll block interaction of other views if *it's actively engaged by the user*. If the exclusiveTouch view isn't being touched, then other views (and the views beneath the button) are totes open for interactions.

Answer (score -1):

I was just reading release notes for iOS 5 and from this version the exclusiveTouch will be set to YES by default. So just keep in mind that it will change with the new version of iOS.

Comment: I checked the docs, where does it say `exclusiveTouch` is set to `YES` by default?

Comment: This is false. From the iOS 5.1 docs: "The default value of this property is NO."